# Android: Access Data from a Service of another application

Tags: java, android

There are two apps, App1 and App2. I have started a service in App1 like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
sendIntent.setAction("getDataFromApp1");
sendIntent.putExtra("dataKey", "This is data I am sending.");
startService(sendIntent);
```

And now I want to get the data[the String object that I have set in Intent using `putExtra()` ] from that service and show it in App2.

So my question is how do I access data from a service created by another app. I have declared the service in Manifest File with android:exported=true.

Comment: use "bound service" pattern then

Comment: I am very new to android, I do not know bound service

Comment: so learn about it, more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to expose content provider in App1 which serves data that can be used in App2. 
and yes you need to make sure exported is set to true.

You can get started with this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Comment: I have put data in the intent using putExtra() in App1.
So I need to extract that data in App2.

Comment: ok this should be fine if App1 is "giving" data to App2 but if App2 is "requesting" data then you would need content provider. Please rephrase your question. it gives "Requesting" sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using `Intent`'s. You can attach any data you want to an `Intent` and you can listen for a certain type of `Intent` in any of your apps.

For example you could send an `Intent` like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(your.custom.action.for.app.two);
sendIntent.putExtra("dataKey", "Pass this text to app two.");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Then in your second app, attach an intent filter to the `Activity` you would like to be launched in your `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your.custom.action.for.app.two" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then in that `Activity` check in your `onCreate` if it was launched via that `Intent` and handle the data like so:

```
 if (getIntent().getAction().equals(your.custom.action.for.app.two) {
     String yourText = getIntent().getStringExtra("dataKey");
 }
```

There is also a lot of other things you would need to consider. Like checking if your second application exists on the users phone, and what if the app is not awake? See [here](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/sharing-data-from-your-android-app-with-other-apps.html) for more information.

Comment: your.custom.action.for.app.two Is this a string name or the package name

Comment: This can be anything you like, it's just a key which you need to match on the other end, like a variable name.

Comment: I want to pass the data via a service not an activity

Comment: You can send a broadcast which will be picked up via a service, just swap startActivity to sendBroadcast and attach the intent-filter to the service.